# Gaussian kernel estimator as Nadaraya-Watson estimator?

Tags: self-study, classification, kernel-smoothing

I'm working on a problem from *"The Elements of Statistical Learning"* (prob. 6.8):

> Suppose that for continuous response
>   $Y$ and predictor $X$, we model the
>   joint density of $X, Y$ using a
>   multivariate Gaussian kernel
>   estimator. Note that the kernel in
>   this case would be the product kernel
>   $\phi_{\lambda}(X) \phi_{\lambda}(Y)$.
>
> (a) Show that the conditional mean $E(Y|X)$
>   derived from this estimate is a
>   Nadaraya-Watson estimator.
>
> (b) Extend this
>   result to classification by providing
>   a suitable kernel for the estimation
>   of the joint distribution of a
>   continuous $X$ and discrete $Y$.

I know that the Nadaraya-Watson estimator is just the weighted average (equation 2.41 and 6.2 in ESL):

> $$\hat f (x_0) = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^N K_{\lambda}(x_0, x_i) y_i}{\sum_{i=0}^N K_{\lambda}(x_0, x_i)}$$

Where $K$ in this case would be the multivariate Gaussian kernel function.

I can think about how to extend this to a classification problem, but am not sure how to approach the first part of this question.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional mean is defined by:

$$E(Y|X)\equiv\int y f(y|x) dy$$

Where $f(Y|X)$ is the conditional density.  Using the product rule, you can show:

$$f(y|x)=\frac{f(y,x)}{f(x)}$$

Substituting this back into the integral you get

$$E(Y|X)\equiv\frac{\int y f(y,x) dy}{f(x)}$$

Which is of the form you seek, if you use the kernel density estimator.

Comment: Could you explain why it is not $ \int \frac{y f(y,x)}{f(x)} dy $ ? How did the denominator of the conditional probability get pulled out of the integral?

Comment: Because it has no dependence on $y$.  Thus in the integral, it is just a constant.